# text field CSS border misbehaving in Google Chrome

Tags: css, google-chrome

When a user focus a text field, I want the border, which is 1px, to be 2px, so In order to avoid the GUI feel jumpy, I set:

```
 margin-bottom:-2px;
```

This plays nice in Firefox but not in Chrome, is this a bug? any solution to have this working in Chrome?

Problem I get is sometimes when I deselect the text field the border sort of stays. This is an example image:

[image: problem in chrome]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the [`outline`](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/outline.html) instead of the border as that does not affect positioning and surrounding objects.

To quote quirksmode.org:

> The outline of a box is almost the
>   same as the border.
>
> The outline is not actually a part of
>   the box, it does not count in any way
>   towards the width or height of a box.